# Jmeter Connection to host:port refused

Tags: path, jmeter

I am trying to write simple test in JMeter. Just to get to some login page. But the problem is there is "nothing" under root of URL - `http://www.some_host.com:port` returns error 404. User must go to `http://www.host.com:port/login` to visit login page - there is no redirection from root url. And when I run the test, this comes in logs:

2015/02/12 14:40:20 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: IOException org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to `http://www.some_host.com:port` refused

Which is true because the correct path is `http://www.some_host.com:port/login`

How to configure JMeter not to search anything under root URL, just go to the path?

Answer (score 0):

Set the value for the path as given below

[image]

You can use 'HTTP Request Defaults' as well - in case if you need to run the same test in multiple environments, it will be really useful - You do  not need to update the server/port details for each and every HTTP request.

[image]

If you use HTTP Request Defaults, leave those Server & port details blank. (By default JMeter will use server and port details mentioned in the HTTP requests. Only if it is blank, It will use HTTP request defaults details)

Comment: Hi Vinoth S - the problem was with "Server Name" when using by domainname - when I use IP it works fine.